# What does this notation mean in Hurst Exponent?

Tags: notation

Could anyone please tell me what the <| ..... |> notation means in this equation?

[Hurst exponent equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW6dA.png)

Comment: Probably expectation of the absolute value of what's bracketed.

Comment: Thanks. As I delve further and further into it, I believe the <> is for a scalar product, and the | | might refer to a norm.